# How to take 360º photos with flutter?

Tags: flutter

There is currently a way to detect camera movement, so that it is possible to take photos of a car for example and make a 360º representation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Flutter currently doesn't have many Panorama libraries for the purpose you are looking for. So you are going to have to use a Android Library alongside the `MethodChannel` to be able to achieve taking panorama pictures.

There are probably a few Android Panorama libraries or ways to implement it for the use you are looking for.

Let me know if you need any further clarification or I misread the question!